# Query executes successfully but still error persists

Tags: android, cordova

I am inserting a row in sqlite table in phonegap using following function. My row is successfully inserted but after that it gives me error message

```
function executeQuery(qry_str){
    var db = getDatabase();
    var response = db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql(qry_str);
    }, successCB, errorCB);
}

function errorCB(){
  console.log('query error');
}

function successCB(){
   console.log('success');
}
```

Please check out the mistake I am doing.

Comment: What is the error in logcat?

Comment: it just displays the error message in errorCB() function 

08-22 08:53:56.134: I/Web Console(25606): query error at file:///android_asset/www/js/database.js:104

Comment: but my value is inserted successfully in the table

Comment: So what is code at line 104?

Comment: 103   function errorCB(){
104        console.log('query error');
105   }

Comment: Pass `err` as parameter in `errorCB()` and inside `errorCB()` function add this code `alert(err.message)`. Check out what is the error message

Comment: I got another error:
08-22 09:11:08.024: E/Web Console(27614): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/database.js:104

it is saying that err is undefined